# Javascript - How to get the sum of the index[1] elements from a 2D array

Tags: javascript

Working on a homework assignment for my development class.
Part of my problem requires me to create a multidimensional array (2D) and get the sum of the second element from each nested array. How can i achieve this? Here is my array:

```
var studentGrades = [['Bob', 85], ['Jim', 76], ['Steve', 92], ['Sue', 83], ['Liz', 65], ['Jack', 77], ['Jo', 96], ['Tim', 80], ['Mike', 53], ['John', 81]];
```

I need to get all the numbers added together.
I realize their index is [1], but I don't know how to write the code to add these together.

Comment: This is NOT a [Freecode.com](http://freecode.com/) - [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Like @PeterL. said, you need to make it look like you attempted/researched/something. Also, the index you need isn't just `[1]`, check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194650/2d-javascript-array)

Answer (score 2):

You have to do something with a for loop `i` (items) and put a `count` variable outside the for loop. Than use index `1`  as a count because this is the number.

This should help you forward with your homework.

More info

1. [For loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
var sum = 0;
for(var x=0; x<arr.length; x++)
    sum += arr[x][1];
```

You just use 2 indexing brackets, though the 2nd index will always be 1. This is unsafe since multidimensional arrays can be jagged so there's no fixed size of the 2nd dimension.

```
var sum = 0;
for(var x=0; x<arr.length; x++)
    if(arr[x].length >= 2)
        sum += arr[x][1];
```

Adding a check for the length of the inner array per iteration is the safer route.

Comment: This is homework. You should not make someone elses homework. You should put them in the right direction

Comment: Niels I appreciate that, but this is just one segment to a larger problem. Next i have to take the sum of the index[1] elements, get an average for them, then make that average score equate to a letter grade, such as 77 = C, or 85 = B....

Comment: @Niels - I always learned best from a proper solution to a problem with a proper explanation accompanying it. If you want to bait people with hints in the hopes they figure it out themselves, that's fine (and a lot of people seem to share that opinion), but not everyone has time for that. There's not one absolute 'way' to learn.

Comment: I also posted a few times on people questions answers for homework. But if you provide resources to find the answers easily. People can learn by doing instead of copy/paste, cus that's not gonna work. Besides if you don't have time to do your homework. You started too late.

Answer (score 1):

Using ECMAScript5 [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to reduce your array to that sum,

```
var sum = studentGrades.reduce(function(sum, pair) {
    return sum + pair[1];
}, 0);
```

Prettifying it with ECMAScript6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions),

```
var sum = studentGrades.reduce((sum, pair) => sum + pair[1], 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two dimensional arrays are just arrays of arrays. Till you get a better grasp of them I would suggest writing out a grid of how it's accessed. For instance, the array a has 3 elements each holding and array of two elements (we'll call b). The indexing would look like this

```
a0b0 a0b1 
a1b0 a1b1
a2b0 a2b1
```

and in your case it is

```
[['Bob', 85],
['Jim', 76],
['Steve', 92]]
```

So to get Jims grade we can look at the index table and it would be a1b1 which translates to studentGrades [1][1].
To iterate over a double dimension arrays you go through the rows then the columns

```
for(var row = 0; row < a.length; row++){
    var b = a[row];
    for(var column = 0; column < b.length; column++){
        var accesingByRowAndColumn = a[row][column];
        var accesingByColumn = b[column];
    }
}
```

If you are just learning, I would not recommend frankensteining a bunch of code together to produce a solution, you will only hurt yourself in the long run. Understand the problem and the tools to solve the problem. I have tutored people where if a problem requires a slight adjustment from code examples in a book they freak out and don’t understand how to do it

Comment: Couple of spelling issues ... a)  Used 'rows' in the loop and b)  misspelled length in 'b.lenght'

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) JavaScript library:

```
var res = alasql('SELECT VALUE SUM([1]) FROM ?',[studentGrades]);
```

Try this example [at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/nebrsv1c/).